# VB.net split string on non-alphanumeric, non-hyphen characters

Tags: vb.net, string, split

Is there a better approach than this for loop?

Basically, for each character in a charArray created from the string to split, if the character is a letter, digit, or hyphen, I append it to a temporary string. When I see a split character or the last character, and the temporary string has value, I add it to the collection to return.

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To (charArrayLength - 1)

        charToInspect = CChar(charArray.GetValue(i))

        If IsLetterOrDigit(charToInspect) Or charToInspect = hyphen Then
            tempString = tempString + charToInspect

            If i = (charArrayLength - 1) Then
               listOfStringToReturn.Add(tempString)
            End If

        ElseIf tempString.Length > 0 Then
            listOfStringToReturn.Add(tempString)
            tempString = String.Empty

        End If
    Next

    Return listOfStringToReturn
```

Comment: You can use [**`string.Split`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) for splitting on a simple separator, or [**`Regex.Split`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx) for more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This logic is already provided by the [**`string.Split`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method, which takes a list of possible separator characters to split on.

```
Return myString.Split("-"C)
```

If you have more complex delimiters, you can look at [**`Regex.Split`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx).

Comment: I'm looking to split on any character except alpha, numeric, and hyphen. But Regex.Split seems clearer.

Comment: Ah. Ya you should be able to handle that with a negated character class, something like `Regex.Split("[^a-zA-Z0-9-]")`